# Error with sonar run

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ps04 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) @ ps04 ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/scanner/api/LogOutput
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.LogOutput
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-01T20:09:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project ps04: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar: org/sonarsource/scanner/api/LogOutput
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.3.0.603/sonar-maven-plugin-3.3.0.603.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.9.0.887/sonar-scanner-api-2.9.0.887.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/leonardo/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.LogOutput
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Can someone help me? I run StartSonar.bat and then I run the project with a maven build and goals sonar:sonar

Furthermore every time I want run StartSonar.bat I must kill java processes.. I don't think it is normal.

- SonarQube version: 5.6.6
- JDK version: 1.8.0_121
- Java plugin version: it was 3.13.1, I updated to 4.10.0.10260 but I still get the same issue

Comment: Have you tested the previous version of sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar  ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add this to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-scanner-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

`org.sonarsource.scanner.api.LogOutput` is included in sonar-scanner-api.jar

Comment: it still doesn't work.. same error.. but, why 2.8 version?

Comment: It doesn’t have to be 2.8. `LogOutput` (sonar-scanner-api.jar) is missing in classpath since `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.LogOutput` is thrown. Check if the jar exists in your maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SonarLint** plugin in eclipse as an alternative, its [available](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) at eclipse marketplace for free.

> SonarLint focuses on analyzing files as they are edited, to catch
>   issues as early as possible. The idea is to prevent new issues to be
>   introduced, more than to detect existing problems. Check if it suits
>   your need.

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem. You must not used MethodTreeImpl Class in that you created custom rule. 
You must not used every class in org.sonar.java.model
And you must update maven.