# Error while running mvn sonar:sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

When I am trying to run mvn sonar:sonar on a maven project I get a `org/sonarsource/scanner/api/LogOutput` class missing error...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project update-details-aggregator: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: org/sonarsource/scanner/api/LogOutput
```

I am using...

SonarQube 6.7.1
sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
jdk 1.8
maven 3.2.5

I have already looked at the question similar to this one on SO but that does not solve my problem ([Error with sonar run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864056/error-with-sonar-run)).

I do have `sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar` in my local maven repository.

Any help will be appreciated.

Detailed error message...

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonarsource/scanner/api/LogOutput
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:657)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:875)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:798)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:281)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:213)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:998)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:994)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:464)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.LogOutput
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 54 more
```

Comment: Use the most recent version of sonar maven plugin 3.0XX see here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

Comment: @khmarbaise I did try with the most recent version: 3.4.0.905. The result was the same.

Comment: remove `org/sonarsource/scanner/api` directory from your local repository, execute mvn command one more time with debug mode (`-X`), verify which version of the `sonar-scanner-api` is downloaded, verify that the jar file is a jar (not for example HTML error page saved as `sonar-scanner-api-XXX.jar`)

Comment: @agabrys: Tried your suggestion. The jar is download, version 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the entire maven repository (.m2/repository) & ran the command. It worked.

Think the local maven repository had some corrupt packages.